Famous Argentinian movie, Young couple struggling to get by living in Buenos Aires
I am pretty sure that this movie is from early 2000's. The actors speak in Spanish and when I saw the movie many years ago it had subtitles on. The genre seemed to me like drama/romance but there was quite a lot of action in the movie as well.
The movie is about a young couple struggling to get by living in Buenos Aires. I can remember vividly the girl wearing a yellow dress. I remember the couple getting to meet the girl's large family where they all have a barbecue and in the evening the couple was drinking beer at the rooftop of the family's house. 
I also remember a dramatic scene where the couple was running on the side of a large bridge. I don't remember if the guy was chasing the girl or both were trying to escape someone that was after them. Now that I am thinking about it, it is possible the couple was involved in drug dealing to survive, and that caused them a lot of trouble.

Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to edit any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

I recall the couple being at an Internet cafe doing something shady and then somebody chases after them in the busy city streets.

This sounds a lot like City of God, but that was Brazilian and in Portuguese (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317248/).  But there were very similar scenes in there, including a girl in a yellow dress, them running from drug dealers, and even a large bridge.

@aryxus The actors where white so it is not the movie you mentioned. It is my strong impression that the setting was Argentina but it could also be Colombia, Venezuela etc.
